# Facing issue while doing registration using volley library?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am getting proper JSON response but I am unable to Register new user the details this is my code please help me in sorting it out.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editTextUsername, editTextEmail, editTextPassword, editTextLastname, editTextPhnno, editTextAddr, editTextCnfpassword;
ProgressBar progressBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    //if the user is already logged in we will directly start the profile activity
    if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Profile.class));
        return;
    }

    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextLastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLastname);
    editTextPhnno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhnno);
    editTextAddr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddr);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextCnfpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCnfpassword);



    findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //if user pressed on button register
            //here we will register the user to server
            registerUser();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //if user pressed on login
            //we will open the login screen
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
        }
    });

}

private void registerUser() {
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String lastname = editTextLastname.getText().toString().trim();
    final String phnno = editTextPhnno.getText().toString().trim();
    final String addr = editTextAddr.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String cnfpassword = editTextCnfpassword.getText().toString().trim();



    //first we will do the validations

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
        editTextUsername.setError("Please enter username");
        editTextUsername.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        editTextEmail.setError("Please enter your email");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        editTextEmail.setError("Enter a valid email");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lastname)) {
        editTextLastname.setError("Please enter your last name");
        editTextLastname.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phnno)) {
        editTextPhnno.setError("Please enter your Mobile No");
        editTextPhnno.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(addr)) {
        editTextAddr.setError("Please enter your address");
        editTextAddr.requestFocus();
        return;
    }



    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        editTextPassword.setError("Enter a password");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cnfpassword)) {
        editTextCnfpassword.setError("Confirm password");
        editTextCnfpassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_REGISTER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    try {
                        //converting response to json object
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        //if no error in response
                        if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //getting the user from the response
                            JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                            //creating a new user object
                            User user = new User(
                                    userJson.getInt("id"),
                                    userJson.getString("cust_username"),
                                    userJson.getString("cust_firstname"),
                                    userJson.getString("cust_lastname"),
                                    userJson.getString("cust_phoneno"),
                                    userJson.getString("cust_address"),
                                    userJson.getString("cust_pass"),
                                    userJson.getString("cust_confirmpass")
                            );

                            //storing the user in shared preferences
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                            //starting the profile activity
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Profile.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("cust_firstname", username);
            params.put("cust_username", email);
            params.put("cust_lastname", email);
            params.put("cust_phoneno", email);
            params.put("cust_address", email);
            params.put("cust_pass", password);
            params.put("cust_confirmpass", password);
            return params;
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

}

}
```

I am getting the json response message correctly but creating new user object is not getting called and user is not getting created.

This is my json:

```
{
"error": "false",
"message": "Customer Listing",
"status_code": "200",
"data": [
    {
        "entity_id": "24851",
        "website_id": "1",
        "email": "m_nuscis@yahoo.com",
        "group_id": "1",
        "increment_id": null,
        "store_id": "1",
        "created_at": "2018-10-09 11:57:41",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-09 12:02:11",
        "is_active": "1",
        "disable_auto_group_change": "0",
        "created_in": "Default Store View",
        "prefix": null,
        "firstname": "Michael",
        "middlename": null,
        "lastname": "Nuscis",
        "suffix": null,
        "dob": null,
        "password_hash": "ab575655eb9df534bd88b085164a14806b53ca6f18f39a635b48f62da37100b4:JxjNy32ZY8zJaBaJrLvy52G2q58fmZrd:1",
        "rp_token": "bf656905c65b543a6210453f61faa415",
        "rp_token_created_at": "2018-10-09 11:57:41",
        "default_billing": "24031",
        "default_shipping": "24031",
        "taxvat": null,
        "confirmation": null,
        "gender": null,
        "failures_num": "0",
        "first_failure": null,
        "lock_expires": null
    }]}
```

I am getting message and status code correctly but i am getting null for the data can any one help me to solve this out? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Your JSON response there is no any user object , that you are parsing .

```
 //getting the user from the response
  JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");
```

You're gonna have to parse `data JSONArray` and then fetch values from it